# JFrame isn't functioning properly

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jframe

I wrote out this code that's supposed to read a file, use a string tokenizer to go through the file, instantiate a Car object and store the object (String, String, int, int) in 2 different lists, one of which is sorted by Make (like car brand) and the other that isn't, which are displayed on a 2-column `JFrame`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Whenever I run it, the frame is completely empty and it's driving me nuts. I can't tell if it's an issue with the frame set-up or the `readFile` method itself.

This is the `CarGUI` class, where I set-up the frame and the `readFile` method.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class CarGUI extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea leftTextArea;
    private JTextArea rightTextArea;
    private StringBuilder leftSide;
    private StringBuilder rightSide;

     public CarGUI() //default constructor for the GUI class
   {
        // Instance variables
       this("Project 1");
   }

    public static ArrayList<Car> unsortedList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    public static ArrayList<Car> sortedList = new ArrayList<Car>();



      public CarGUI() //default constructor for the GUI class
   {
        // Instance variables
       this("Project 1");
   }




 public CarGUI(String title) //the 1-argument parameter constructor 
    {
        // Call the super class constructor to initialize the super
        // class variables before initializing this class's variables
        super(title);

        // Configure the JFrame
        // Configure the JFrame components we inherited
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocation(200, 200);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2)); //1 row and 2 column
        this.leftSide = new StringBuilder("Unsorted Cars\n"); 
        this.rightSide = new StringBuilder("Sorted Cars\n");
        this.leftTextArea = new JTextArea(this.leftSide.toString(), 5, 20);
        this.rightTextArea = new JTextArea(this.rightSide.toString(), 5, 20);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.leftTextArea);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.rightTextArea);
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
            leftSide.append(unsortedList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
            rightSide.append(sortedList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
        }
        this.leftTextArea.setText(this.leftSide.toString());
        this.rightTextArea.setText(this.rightSide.toString());
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


public void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File myFile = new File("Cars.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String delimiter = ",";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);
        int tokenCount = new StringTokenizer(line, ",").countTokens(); //counts the tokens, should yield 4 
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){ 
        if(tokenCount != 4){ //if there isn't exactly 4 tokens, print the rest to the console
            System.out.println(tokenizer.toString());
        }
        else {
            //newCar(Make, Model, Year, Mileage);
            Car newCar = new Car(tokenizer.nextToken(), tokenizer.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            unsortedList.add(newCar);
            sortedList.addAll(unsortedList);
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
    selectionSort(sortedList);
}
```

This is `selectionSort` method where the magic is supposed to happen:

```
public void selectionSort(ArrayList<Car> sortedList2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList2.size(); i++) {
            int min = i;            
            for (int j = min + 1; j < sortedList2.size(); j++)
                if (sortedList2.get(j).getMake().compareTo(sortedList2.get(min).getMake()) < 0)
                    min = j;  
            Car temp1 = sortedList2.get(i);
            Car temp2 = sortedList2.get(i);
            Car notTemp = sortedList2.get(min);
            temp1 = notTemp; // sortedList2.get(i) = sortedList2.get(min);
            notTemp = temp2; // sortedList2.get(min) = sortedList2.get(i);
            //doing this because I need to set a variable on the left-hand side
        }

    }
}
```

`Project1`

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class Project1 {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
         String file = "cars.txt";
            CarGUI testGUI = new CarGUI();
            testGUI.readFile(file);

    }
}
```

It COULD be an issue with the `selectionSort` method. I set it up with the `temp`, `temp2`, and `notTemp` due to the fact Eclipse wouldn't accept 
`sortedList2.get(i) = sortedList2.get(min);`, since

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

Thoughts? Don't ask why I'm using a selection sort method, it's required. :(

Comment: I dont see where you are writing anything to your GUI...?

Comment: I don't see where you fill your text areas?

Comment: I don't see a setVisible on the JFrame. Is it even showing up? Are you writing anything into leftTextArea or rightTextArea? I don't see anything being done with unsortedList or sortedList after they are populated.

Comment: BTW - shouldn't `sortedList2.get(i) = sortedList2.get(min)` instead be `sortedList2.set(i) = sortedList2.get(min)`? (One less `g`, one more `s`.)

Comment: *"Don't ask why I'm using a selection sort method, it's required."* I was about to suggest dumping the two lists in favor of a `JTable` so I would've asked, had you not explained. So this is for teaching purposes?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah, basically. Which sucks for the way I coded it because I stored the Car object into 2 ArrayList so I had to make the selection sort method work with ArrayLists, which was just annoying.

Comment: Maybe it's trying to teach you that just because a problem ***can*** be solved one way, does not mean it's the **best** way (being generous). ;)

Comment: Please post the content of file `cars.txt`. That will help us to understand the scenario.